# Explanation BooleanGroup Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm a complete newbie to laravel and laravel nova.

I created a booleangroup because I need multiple checkboxes. But here comes the problem.
When I try to submit a form, to add a 'office' in the backend, there comes a red popup: Array to string conversion. I've searched through google, check the docs, but it's not clear to me, what exactly the problem is.

This is the code from my resource file

```
    public function fields(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return [
            Slug::make('Slug')->from('Title')->required()->withMeta(['extraAttributes' => [
                'readonly' => true
            ]]),
            Text::make('Title')->required(),
            Text::make('Slogan')->required(),
            Text::make('Featured_image')->required(),
            Markdown::make('Short_description')->required(),
            Markdown::make('Long_description')->required(),
            Boolean::make('Available')->required(),
            Number::make('Amount_employees')->required(),
            Text::make('Address')->required(),
            Text::make('Email')->required(),
            Text::make('Phone')->required(),
            BooleanGroup::make('Services')->options([
                'schuldenbewind' => 'Schuldenbewind',
                'budgetbeheer' => 'Budgetbeheer',
                'mentorschap' => 'Mentorschap'
            ]),
            Text::make('Aangesloten bij branchevereniging', 'Joined_associations')->required(),
            Boolean::make('Is_published')->required()
        ];
    }
```

This is the code in my model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Kantoren extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'slug', 
        'title', 
        'slogan', 
        'featured_image', 
        'short_description', 
        'long_description', 
        'available' => 'array', 
        'amount_employees', 
        'address', 
        'email', 
        'phone', 
        'services' => 'array', 
        'joined_associations'
    ];
}
```

Can someone explain what is causing the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved it myself. I used the example of Nova. And it worked

```php
protected $casts = [
    'permissions' => 'array'
];
```